# How to provide the association between the dialog and a button?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Please Kindly Help in Making the association between the Dialog and the button in vC++

Comment: Is the button on the dialog, or is the button supposed to display the dialog?  Which comes first?

Answer (score 1):

If by "the Dialog" you mean "the Dialog class" then I assume you're trying to access a dialog button from within the Dialog class for that dialog.  If so, then try right-clicking the button in the resource editor and select "Add Variable".  This will then add a variable to the dialog class which is associated with the button in the dialog.